# IBOutlet not connecting in SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

All,

I have this in swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
```

So if i go in the storyboard, I should be able to see that, and I should be able to connect it like this :

[image]

So I should be able to go to 'New Referencing Outlet' and drag it on the view controller (yellow tab at the top) and I should see 'tableView' and  connect it. This doesn't happen , I am confused why !

Comment: Can you check whether the correct viewcontroller is being pointed in identity inspector -> Custom Class?

Comment: There is only one view controller on my storyboard

Comment: yes the ViewController is in the Class

Comment: i try this in my case it is happening go and see in your swift file wether circle on the left of tableview outlet is filled or not.

Answer (score 1):

Do no type following line in advance.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! // <-- this line
```

Instead, add a UIComponent in your storyboard first and then using "assistant editor" drag the connection link in your swift file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the picture you posted I can see you are looking for `IBOutlet`, but you selected the `tableView` not the whole controller.

Click on the white status bar (where yellow - controller and 2 oranges - responder and exit buttons are) then you will see your `IBOutlet`