# Cannot find the error in this sequence. Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift

I have just started to code, but I have already encountered some error which I cannot figure out. Would you please help me?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var getNumber: UITextField!

    @IBAction func computePrime(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if let userString = getNumber.text {                                            // Convert input to Int
            let userNumber = Int(userString)

            if let number = userNumber {
                var i = 2                                                               // Variable declaration
                var prime = true

                while i < number {                                                      // Prime calculation
                    if number & i == 0 {
                        prime = false
                        i = number
                    } else {
                        i += 1
                    }
                }

                if prime == false {                                                     // Output result
                    displayResult.text = "It is not prime"
                } else {
                    displayResult.text = "It is prime"
                }
            } else {
                displayResult.text = "Please enter a positive whole number"                 // Error message in case value entered is not good
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var displayResult: UILabel!





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

When I try to run it, the app crashes and it gives me this error:

> "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

highlighting this line:

> "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {"

from the AppDelegate.swift file, which I have not modified.

How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get the line of the error. Most likely an IBOutlet is not connected. By the way: Your prime algorithm does not work.

Comment: Learn to debug an iOS app - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have connected in `Storyboard` the getNumber and displayResult (IBOutlet) object.
Check that answer:

[IBOutlet not connecting in SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060450/iboutlet-not-connecting-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The highlighted line is at the application delegate because the system regressed all the way back to the top trying to find a layer with an exception handler for the exception that was thrown.  Check the last few lines of the Xcode console for a description of the exception which may tell you where it was caused.

You can add an "Exception Breakpoint" to stop execution at the moment of the exception to see the point of origin.  Many articles exist on how to do this.